# PDF-link in iframe not opening in mainwindow

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

I have a site whith an iframe showing a PDF. 
(left is my menu and right is the pdf-content).
This PDF contains a link to my or an other site. Now when the user klicks on a link in the PDF eg. www.mysite.com it opens in the iframe.
How can I force my site to open this link in the top-Level (same window) and not in the iframe?

I tryed `<base target="_top" />` `<base target="_blank" />` in my mainheader without any success.